# AWS ECS: How to communicate between services within ECS Cluster without using ALB? Is there a way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

Suppose I have a service say *auth*(port:8080) which has 3 tasks running and let's say I have another service say *config-server*(port:8888), 2 tasks running, where *auth* will load the configuration properties from, similar to spring cloud config server.

**Launch Type: EC2**

***auth* service running on 8080 |
*config-server* service running on 8888**

Now, in order to access *config-server* from *auth*, do I have to use ALB to call *config-server* or I can call using service name, like http://config-server:8888?

I tried but it's not working. Did I misunderstand any concept here?

I would like to get some insight on this.
This is how my [Service Discovery Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5dsk.png) looks like.

EDITS:

I created a private namespace test.lo and still not working..

> curl http://config-server.test.lo
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: config-server.test.lo

Comment: Have you setup [service discovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html) for the two services of yours?

Comment: I did and with the same name as that of service. The namespace is local | Private

Comment: Could you be more specific. What does it mean it "doesn't work"? You get any errors, timeouts? How have you setup R53, and other service discovery settings.

Comment: I am getting errors like bad port spec, could not resolve the hostname and bad host from inside the container as well as outside. I have added a snapshot of the configuration details to the question.

Comment: Shoudn't you use full name of the form <service-name>.<namespace-name>?

Comment: Tried that also, no luck. My new namespace is test.lo
curl http://config-server.test.lo
>>curl: (6) Could not resolve host: config-server.test.lo

Comment: Have you checked R53? It should contain the private hosted zone `test.lo` as well as A and SRV records for each task in the container. So at least we know they exist.

Comment: I obviously assume the VPC has all dns setting enabled?

Answer (score 8):

These are general things to check.

1. Ensure that `enableDnsHostnames` and `enableDnsSupport` options for VPC are enabled.
2. Don't use `local` as a private namespace. It's a reserved name.
3. Check private hosted zone created in Route 53 and verify that it has all the A (and SRV if used) correctly set to the private IP address of the service's tasks.
4. Private hosted zone can be resolved only from the inside of the same VPC as the ECS service. Thus to check if they work, can create an instance in the VPC and inspect from there.
5. Use `dig` tool to check if the DNS actually resolves the private dns name into private IP addresses. It should return multiple addresses, one for each task in a service.
6. If using `awsvpc` network mode can using either A or SRV record types. Thus if SRV does not work, it could be worth checking with A record.